# How to use non-monadic functions in a bind operation

Tags: haskell, monads

I feel like I should already know this, but how could I use `fromMaybe` in one line instead of breaking it into 2 with a `let`?

```
main = do
    maybePort <- lookupEnv "PORT"
    let port = fromMaybe "4020" maybePort
    putStrLn $ "Listening on:" ++ port
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [`fmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) or [`<$>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-) like this:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))

main = do
    port <- fromMaybe "4020" <$> lookupEnv "PORT"
    putStrLn $ "Listening on:" ++ port
```

Comment: You actually don't need `fmap` or `<$>` at all in this example code. `putStrLn $ "Listening on:" ++ fromMaybe "4020" maybePort` works just fine once you've got the `lookupEnv` call and you can even one-liner it as `lookupEnv "PORT" >>= putStrLn . ("Listening on: " ++) . fromMaybe "4020"`. I guess since it's presumably also used later (for actually binding the port) yours is the correct answer though.

Comment: @ChrisDrost of course there is more than one solution to most problems - this is just the first that came to my mind - why don't you make your comment into another answer? - BTW: IMO `<$>` is usually rather readable and I would choose it over `>>=` here, but that's just preferences